# Parsing postgres date in logstash using datefilter plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using `logstash`to read the `postgres` data using `jdbc` input plugin and push to `elastic`

The data is coming properly and things seems to be working fine just for a small problem i.e.

My logs table has a field `requesttimestamp` with datatype of `timestamp`. Since there is a historical data and also to ensure that the timelines are based on the data and not the time of run, I am trying to set the value of `@timestamp` with `requettimestamp`.

the filter configuration is as follows:

`{
  match => ["requesttimestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
 }`

but while running it is tagging it as `_dateparsefailure` and using the system time as `@timestamp`

I also tried using the following format : `ISO8601` but nothing seems to be working.

I am sure it is something simple but not able to put the finger to it.

Comment: What is the value in the field `requesttimestamp`? What's the value when logstash prints it (with output stdout)?

Comment: its as follows `"requesttimestamp":"2017-11-01T18:29:22.499Z"` i had even tried giving the following format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` but i still get `_dateparsefailure`

Comment: I have tested the example (`"2017-11-01T18:29:22.499Z"`) with ISO8601 and it worked on my platform. Perhaps when you're receiving it, the field `requesttimestamp` is already a timestamp, so that's why the match fails. Other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. since logstash is directly reading from the database the the type is directly being derived as `timestamp` and hence seems to be failing during the filter step. I removed the filter itself and is working fine now ! Thanks for the direction